# form page in flutter but there i found one bug once i enter name in textform field after i select radio button that time text will refreshing

Tags: flutter, dart, radio-button, textfield

```
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
                    
                          child: TextFormField(
                              
                              decoration:const InputDecoration(
                              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 192, 77, 230)),
                              ),
                              hintText: "Head Name",
                           
                          ),
                        ),
                       
                            child: Row(
                              
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                              children: [

                                const Text("Select Gender : "),
                                
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Radio(value: "male", groupValue: gender, onChanged: (value) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        gender = value.toString();
                                        
                                      });
                                      
                                    }),
                                    const Text('Male',style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 162, 162, 162),
                                    ),)
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                     Radio(
                                        value: "female", 
                                        groupValue: gender, 
                                        onChanged: (value){
                                          setState(() {
                                              gender = value.toString();
                                          });
                                        },
                                        
                                    ),
                                    const Text('Female',style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 162, 162, 162),
                                    ),)
                                  ],
                                ),
                                

                              ],
                           
                          ),
        ),
    )
```

I created form page in flutter but there i getting one bug if i entered text in textfield later i will select gender that time textfield will refreshed please help me how to solve this problem also same problem getting in selecting image also i think problem in textformfield